# Rails. Necessary to simple_form 2 of the field combine and store in one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm novice developer.
There is a problem: it is necessary to simple_form 2 of the field combine and store in one field of the database table. How to do it?

Source code to the example I have. I'm just starting and do not know where to start.

**UPDATE**
Reformulate the question. 
In several fields there form two or more. These fields are to be stored in one database field, with share values ​​"-" sign. 
Way serialize to help? Or the right to use any other way?

Comment: I didn't really get the question. Could you please rephrase it? You need to combine values of two fields of form, and save the result into db?

Comment: Yes, Andrey. 2 fields => 1 field DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be to serialize multiple data into a single field. Here is an example:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :full_name
  # other model code
end
```

Now to save the record:

```
User.new(:full_name => {'firstname' => 'Tom', 'lastname' => 'Smith'})
```

Now when you call `user.full_name` you'll get a hash with both the `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. 
I reformulated the question. What do you think about this?

Comment: I think using serialise is still the way to go. You can format the data anyway you like once you have pulled it out of the database. The hash format will allow you to easily manipulate it, using Ruby